# Постановка запятой в предложении перед "как"

Tags: запятые, как

Нужна ли запятая в предложении?

> Когда я начала писать(,) как неграмотная малолетка?

Answer (score -1):

Если бы от первого лица было сказано: «Я как неграмотная малолетка...», это считалось бы признанием себя таковой (я — неграмотная малолетка). Но это не так, — в намерения автора не входит приравнивание. Он говорит о сравнении возможностей. Здесь сравнительный оборот, и сравнительный союз при нём.

> Голос звенел, как колокольчик.

Перед *как* запятая может не ставиться, если оборот с союзом входит в состав сказуемого и предложение без такого оборота не имеет законченного смысла (например: *Она ведёт себя как хозяйка*). Но это, кажется, не относится к конкретному случаю.